# WPF RadBusyIndicator Using MVVM Command Pattern Not Firing

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

I am attempting to make a RadBusyIndicator appear while a process completes on the backend. I have a button bound to a Command:

**XAML Page**

```
<telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="BusyIndicator" IsBusy="{Binding IsProcessing, Mode=TwoWay}">
     <!-- Form to fill -->
     <Button Name="BtnDoSomething" Content="Do Something" Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" />
</telerik:RadBusyIndicator>
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class SomethingViewModel
{
    private readonly DoSomethingService _doSomethingService;

    public SomethingViewModel() 
    {
        _doSomethingService = new DoSomethingService();
        CloseCuCommand = new Command(x => HandleCloseCuCommand());
    }

    private bool _isProcessing;
    public bool IsProcessing
    {
        get { return _isProcessing; }
        set
        {
            _isProcessing = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsProcessing));
        }
    }

    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand{ get; private set; }
    private void HandleDoSomethingCommand()
    {
        IsProcessing = true;
        _doSomethingService.LongProcess()
        IsProcessing = false;
    }
 }
```

As you can see, I have the BusyIndicator bound to a boolean on the ViewModel. I've confirmed that the OnPropertyChanged is being hit, but it doesn't actually update value on the XAML page.

From what I understand, this has to do with the Single-threaded nature of WPF. However, I haven't been able to find a way to thread a Command that is bound like this. I've attempted adding the threading logic to the CodeBehind but I still can't handle the dispatcher on the Command side.

Answer (score 1):

Set the IsProcessing by **BeginInvoke** method in where you need, because they are in different thread.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
 new Action(() =>
 {
 IsProcessing= true;
 })
 );
```

Comment: This did not work. The BusyIndicator still did not activate. Are there more details you're missing?

Comment: In Xaml, you maybe need to add DataContext in before the Property, just like:Binding DataContext.IsProcessing / Binding DataContext.DoSomethingCommand

Comment: I failed to include the CodeBehind .xaml.cs, but the VM is bound to the xaml page already.